# take next n lines from a file until EOF reached

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, python-itertools

I have a function, which yields specific columns from a csv file as a list and appends them to a list until a limit of n is reached. The problem is...

```
LIMIT = 10
def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
         header = next(infile)
         for line in infile:
             # get column by header and append to mylist
             yield mylist
new_list = []
for dataset in read_csv('some.csv'):
    new_list.append(dataset)
    if len(new_list) == LIMIT:
        # call a func to create xml file with dataset

# grab the remaining data
else:
    new_list.append(dataset)
    # call a func to create xml file with dataset
    new_list = []
```

...this (ugly) for/else workaround. I've read about `itertools.islice` and `itertools.takewhile`
How would you write this task w/o using a for/else?

```
for dataset in itertools.islice(read_csv('some.csv'), LIMIT):
    new_list.append(dataset)
```

I'm stuck here, because i have to find a way to capture `islice`s StopIteration and repeat it until `read_csv()` is done

Any ideads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for-loop over `islice` won't raise `StopIteration`, so no need to worry about that and `islice` takes care of EOF as well. So, at the end of the loop you can simply *call a func to create xml file with data*. And instead of looping over `islice` I'd suggest you to simply call `list()` on it to get its data in a list.

```
data = read_csv('some.csv')
new_list = list(islice(data, LIMIT))
# call a func to create xml file with data
# do something with remaining `data`
```

Or if you want to break the data from `read_csv` in chunks of size `LIMIT` then you can use the [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools:

```
from itertools import islice, izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue='', *args)

for dataset in grouper(read_csv('some.csv'), LIMIT):
    # call a func to create xml file with dataset
```

Note that if the number of items returned by `read_csv` are not an exact multiple of `LIMIT` then the last dataset will contain the `''` fill value.

Comment: That's it. I've read through the docs and might have overlooked it.